# Our "Popularity Trends" always show 0 views inside sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, administration, site-usage, popularity-trends

We have a SharePoint 2013 on-premises server. and the users have reported that the "Popularity Trends" report will always be empty:-

[image]

so i read this link @ https://briantjackett.com/2013/08/26/powershell-script-to-workaround-no-data-in-sharepoint-2013-usage-reports/ and when i run the proposed script:-

```
> $aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics*"} 
> $aud | fl    
> $prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests"}
> $prud | fl
```

I got False for the "EnableReceivers", as follow:-
[image]

also when i checked Central admin > Application management > Manage Service Application > "Usage and Health Data Collection Service Application", i found that it is started as follow:-
[image]

so not sure what is going on? the problem that the fix on this link https://briantjackett.com/2013/08/26/powershell-script-to-workaround-no-data-in-sharepoint-2013-usage-reports/ is not an official fix, and i am afraid of running it... so can anyone advice why our "Popularity Trends" always show 0 views..

Answer (score 0):

According to your post, the root cause is related to the Event Receiver that are both disabled.

As a workaround, please enable the Event Receivers and register it to your content farm.

Run the below PowerShell in content farm: for enabling the Page Requests event receivers:

```
$prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests"}
$prud.EnableReceivers=  $true
$prud.Enabled = $true
$prud.Update()
$aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests*"}
$aud | fl
```

Run the below PowerShell in content farm: for enabling the Analytics event receivers:

```
$aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics*"}
$aud.EnableReceivers=  $true
$aud.Enabled = $true
$aud.Update()
$prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics"}
$prud | fl
```

Run the below PowerShell in Content farm to attach the page request receiver:

```
$prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests"}
$prud.Receivers.Add("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Applications, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c","Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.Internal.ViewRequestUsageReceiver")
$prud.EnableReceivers=$true
```

Run the below PowerShell in Content farm to attach the Analytics receiver:

```
$aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics*"}
$aud.Receivers.Add("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Applications, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c", "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.Internal.AnalyticsCustomRequestUsageReceiver")
$aud.EnableReceivers = $true
```

Then wait for 24 hours and check if everything is working as expected.

And there is a blog for your reference: [SharePoint 2016 Popularity Trends and Usage data return no results](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51478.sharepoint-2016-popularity-trends-and-usage-data-return-no-results.aspx)